# Best practices for managing $_GET and url strings

Tags: php

In my application certain query strings will perform certain class methods and I am currently using a bunch of switch statements to achieve this. For instance:

```
switch (true) {
   case isset($_GET['action']):
       switch($_GET['action']) {
           case 'delete':
               if ($obj->delete($x)) {
                   // do something
               } else {
                  // do something
               }
           break;
           case 'update':
               if ($obj->update($x)) {
                   // do something
               } else {
                  // do something
               }
           break;
           case 'edit':
               if ($obj->edit($x)) {
                   // do something
               } else {
                  // do something
               }
           break;
       }
   break;
   and so forth.....................
}
```

The above is a toned down example, in some cases there are further switch statements within. I find using this method is much cleaner than a bunch of if statements - but what I am really looking for is a much more efficient way of handling these calls, as this is now starting to become difficult to maintain.

Is what I am doing bad practice?

Are there suggested patterns I can read up on for this?

Comment: What does the "so forth" part look like? More `$_GET` sniffing?

Comment: What are the other actions? It doesn't look like a monster of a script if you are dealing with the main 4 (CRUD)...

Comment: Same pattern throughout, checking different get variables are set and then further checking. My application is not huge but this is the same pattern used thoughout about 10+ pages. I suppose I was just curious to see whether there are any better ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is bad practice**. When your `switch`es get out of hand, you're doing it wrong!

**OTP**'s idea is good but I'd change it a bit.

**I'd convert the entire handling part into a class if it's so large.** *See proof of concept below.* A class with methods named as the action is far more maintainable than `switches from hell`.

```
/**
* Handles the actions.
*/
class GetHandler {
    /**
    * Place errors here from the handling method.
    */
    public $Errors = array();

    public function __construct(){
        // setup the $obj here and stuff
    }

    public function update(){
        // do stuff
    }

    public function edit(){
        // do stuff
    }

    public function delete(){
        // do stuff
    }

    public function __invoke(){
        // no handler handling here
        $this->Errors[] = 'Invalid action performed.';
    }
} // class GetHandler;

// Expose the GetHandle in globals if this code is not in global scope
$GLOBALS['GetHandler'] = $GetHandler = new GetHandler();

// Now forward the action to the handler
if(!empty($_GET['action']) and is_string($_GET['action'])){
    // Now check if the method exists
    if(method_exists($GetHandler, $_GET['action'])){
        call_user_func(array($GetHandler, $_GET['action']));
    }else{
        // invoke the object and let it handle errors
        call_user_func($GetHandler);
    }
}else{
    // invoke the object and let it handle errors
    call_user_func($GetHandler);
}

// Later on, anywhere... you can do error checking
if(!empty($GLOBALS['GetHandler']->Errors)){
    foreach($GLOBALS['GetHandler']->Errors as $Error){
        echo $Error, PHP_EOL;
    }
}else{
    // handle a success
    // use $GLOBALS['GetHandler'] custom properties to get success data
}
```

*Still, IMO, huge switches are not good.*

Answer (score 0):

If that's really your code, how about:

```
$x = '???';
if(isset($_GET['action'])){
  $action = $_GET['action'];

  if(method_exists($obj, $action) && $obj->{$action}($x)){
     // printf('%s done!', $action);
  }
}
```

Comment: The above was just a toned down example of how I am managing the get variables. In essence each first level switch is the door to a specific area/page which then contains further actions specific to that area, and so forth...